# Error in accessing oracle dataSource in spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I had written the code to connect my oracle database in my spring-config.xml.

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >

        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:revanth" />
        <property name="username" value="revanth" />
        <property name="password" value="revanth"/>

    </bean>

    <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
    <bean id="studentJDBCTemplate" class="dao.StudentJDBCTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

and the error i am getting while running it is cannot access the dataSource and driverClassName.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at dao.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

and my main class code as follows

```
ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate = (StudentJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("studentJDBCTemplate");
```

Comment: is revanth a valid service name or sid?

Comment: Make sure the proper JDBC driver jar `ojdbc14.jar` is placed under class-path. [Read more...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290214/maven-camel-spring-oracle-error-creating-bean-java-lang-illegalstateexception)